# How can I debug my docker container with phpStorm

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, boot2docker

Under the following IP my Container run successful in my Webbrowser

http://192.168.99.100:32775

I have also create a volume to share files between my container and my filesystem

```
docker run --name lampf -d -p 32775:80 -v /Users/sja/Sites/lamkepf2:/var/www/html --link=lampf_db:db codinglimo/apache_php540_gs_imgmck_pdflib9
```

Now I install also xDebug successful in my container with the following xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/temp/profiledir"
```

PHPStorm is also configured

http://img2.picload.org/image/iowdpww/xdebug.png

But my Breakpoints in my index.php are ignored?
What is my mistake?

**Problem is solve with help from Sergey**

My new xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_enable=on
#xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/temp/profiledir"
```

Comment: Maybe you should set ip your host machine in `xdebug.remote_host`?

Comment: thx, I delete xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 and set xdebug.remote_connect_back=On

Comment: It might be useful for someone else, but I also had to set up path mappings to map the local files to where they're mounted in the container. Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Servers then add a new one

Comment: How are you running your container? I'm interested in port mapping mainly. Are you mapping container's port 9000 to port 9000 outside (`-p 9000:9000`)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your Docker container can't see your PHP Storm IDE with the IP 127.0.0.1, typically the host is 172.17.42.1 from within a container. Also remote_connect_back won't work well probably. Try setting it up like this:

```
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.42.1 
xdebug.remote_connect_back=Off
```

You might need to look for a proper way to know the host's IP within your container, 172.17.42.1 is just the default but it might not always be that.

Comment: Enter the container running PHP end type this at the CLI: `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'`

Comment: My default was 172.17.0.1

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me just executing inside the container:

```
pecl install -o -f xdebug \
&& rm -rf /tmp/pear \
&& echo "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on"  >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_host=172.17.42.1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "memory_limit = 64M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
```

And then, restarting the container.

172.17.42.1 is the default IP of the host, when running Docker.
You can obtain the IP of your host executing in the container:

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

Comment: instead of above command you can also run ifconfig where docker daemon is running. 
docker0  inet addr:172.17.0.1 (an example)

Answer (score 0):

I found more automated solution
In my ENTRYPOINT i ran the startServices script

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST_IP=`/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'`
head -n -1 /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini > /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.tmp
echo "xdebug.remote_host="$HOST_IP >> /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.tmp
rm /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
mv /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.tmp /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini

/usr/bin/supervisord
```

It takes the current ip address of the host machine and replaces the line in xdebug.ini, then running the supervisord witch is starting all the stuff

My initial xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
[xdebug]
; priority=999
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_connect_back = Off
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 128
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
```

After running the script, i`ll get something like this

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
[xdebug]
; priority=999
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_connect_back = Off
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 128
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1
```

Where 172.17.0.1 is my current host ip

Comment: The remote IP (172.17.0.1) does not work for me too. I can get xdebug communicating with my IDE though if I set remote_host to the IP of my Docker virtual ethernet adapter. Might be related to this issue

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/37

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the ip 172.17.0.1, entry script will do the trick for you,  it will take the correct  ip address automatically. I have checked this solution on about a 10 computers, and all the time it works perfectly